# Facebook development - add app to group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have not done any Facebook development (at all).

I want to create an app and add it to a Facebook group. This does not seem to be possible, is that true? ID not,what are the alternatives?

I want to store and display extra info on each user in the group. Like if the group was about movies. I want each of my group members anwer they fav movies/genres were and display it with their pic and name (for example)

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: Ok. Good to know. @Everybody: what are the alternatives? I have seen some web sites with a facebook top bar